# How can I reconfigure the way my JsonFormatter serializes dates?

Tags: c#, json

It would seem that Asp.Net MVC Web API uses a default serialization format with more than three digits for the fractions of a second.

When dates with more than three digits for the fractions of a second are formatted with AngularJS the dates do not display correctly

Here is the way I have set up serialization:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Currently dates appear as:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ
```

Is there a way that I can configure date default serialization format to just show:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Javascript allows the decimals, as they are permitted in the ISO8601 format.  Is there something specific you are doing in Angular that would prevent it from accepting them?  Can you show the code where you parse the string to a date in angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom converter like this.

```
public class MyDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                           object value,
                                                  JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value)
                               .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
        }
}
```

Then, configure it for JSON.NET to use.

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyDateTimeConverter());
```

Comment: Looks good, but watch out for the `.Kind`.  If `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Utc` then it should probably have the `Z` at the end.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. If OP thinks the custom converter solution is really needed, OP might need to build on this and make it a bit more flexible :).

Answer (score 1):

While I have not tried this out myself, check out [JSON Dates are Different in ASP.NET MVC and Web API](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/json-dates-are-different-in-aspnet-mvc.html#.UcN2a_nVAwE).

The blog entry makes reference to using the date values in `KnockoutJS`, but I am hoping this will provide a lead for you to get it working in `AngularJS` as well.